# Is there a better way to use converting the float values in fillna() into an object dtype?

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

Is there a better way to do this conversion of the fillna values with object datatype :

```
df =df.fillna({"first_col":0.0, "second_col":0.0})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need check `downcast` parameter, [`Dataframe.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Comment: does that mean the float will be considered as an object type after I  `df =df.fillna({"first_col":0.0, "second_col":0.0},downcast = 'infer')`

Comment: no, but you may not need to use `astype(int)` if the values ​​in the column are already integers, `df.fillna({"first_col":0 "second_col":0},downcast = 'infer')`

Answer (score 1):

I have first converted it to the int type and then the object type.

```
# float (-> fillna) -> int -> object

# converting to int type
df["first_col"] = df["first_col"].astype("int")
df["second_col"] = df["second_col"].astype("int")

# converting to obj. type
df["first_col"] = df["first_col"].astype("object")
df["second_col"] = df["second_col"].astype("object")
```